# How can a list be called from one class to another class in Python?

Tags: python

```
class A:
     myList = ['0', '2', '3']
     def hello (self):
          print("Hello!")

class B:
```

How can I put the myList in class A into class B?

I tried to simply do "print(myList)" in class B, with no luck. Is there even a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can access it with `A.myList`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes Python so much easier ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myList` menber *belongs* to class `A` so, if you want to access it, you need to use `A.myList`.

However, that's often a bad idea in object-oriented code since it means the member is not under the control of the class (i.e., is not encapsulated):

```
class A:
    myList = [0, 2, 3]                  # Normal variable, public.
    def doSomething(self):
        print('A', A.myList)

class B:
    def doSomethingBad(self):
        print('B', A.myList)            # Print and modify original.
        A.myList = [42]

a = A()
b = B()
a.doSomething()
b.doSomethingBad()
a.doSomething()                         # Shows changed value.
```

The output of that shows that encapsulation has been bypassed:

```
('A', [0, 2, 3])
('B', [0, 2, 3])
('A', [42])
```

Ideally, you'd want a member function that could return you a *copy* of the member so you could do whatever you want with it, without breaking encapsulation, something like:

```
class A:
    __myList = [0, 2, 3]                # Dunder variable, private.
    def doSomething(self):
        print('A', A.__myList)

    @classmethod                        # Class method to return copy.
    def getCopy(self):
        return [x for x in A.__myList]

class B:
    def doSomethingGood(self):
        myList = A.getCopy()            # Get copy for print and change.
        print('B', myList)
        myList = [42]

a = A()
b = B()
a.doSomething()
b.doSomethingGood()
a.doSomething()                         # Still shows original.
```

Using that method, encapsulation is enforced:

```
('A', [0, 2, 3])
('B', [0, 2, 3])
('A', [0, 2, 3])
```

If you *did* try to access/change `A`'s original copy by using `print('B', A.__myList)` within `B`, you'd see it was forbidden:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pax/testprog.py", line 13, in doSomething
    print('B', A.__myList)
AttributeError: class A has no attribute '_B__myList'
```